# Modification of the particular solution of a nonhomogenous 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Studying engineering mathematics, I came up with this question.

I will start with an example. Consider the following:

$$y''(x) \ - \ y'(x) \ = \ \frac{1}{2}e^x$$

From the LHS the characteristic equation gives

$$\lambda = 0, 1$$

and thus the general solution to the homogenous equation is

$$y_h(x)=Ae^{0x}+Be^x = A+Be^x$$

where A and B are constants.

However after that I want to find the particular solution and I wondered:

**Is it ok to use $y_p(x)=e^x$? or do I have to use $y_p(x)=xe^x$?**

I extended this idea. For the ODE $$y''+py'+qy=r(x)$$ where p and q are constants and r(x) is trigonometric, exponential or polynomial function, let's assume that the homogenous solution can be expressed in the form $y_h(x)=Cf(x)+Dg(x)$ where C and D are constants. And I recognise from r(x) that the ansatz for the particular solution should be $y_p(x)=Eg(x)$.

**In this case, do I modify the ansatz by multiplying by $x$, i.e., setting $y_p(x)=xEg(x)$, or do I leave it as it was since $g(x)$ is different from $f(x)+g(x)$?**

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: If $y=Ce^X$ is a solution the homogeneous equation, then you already know that $y''-y' = 0 \ne \frac12e^x$, so it won’t work as a particular solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1) $For the particular solution the guess should be:
$$y_p=Cxe^x$$
Since $e^x$ is already part of the homogeneous solution.

Note that you can rewrite the DE:
$$y''(x) \ - \ y'(x) \ = \ \frac{1}{2}e^x$$
As:
$$( y'(x)e^{-x})'= \ \frac{1}{2}$$
And integrate twice.

---

$2) $For the second question in that case, you may have to multiply by $x$ or $x^2$ the ansatz if it's part of the solution to the homogeneous DE. This is the rule for a second order linear DE with constant coefficients as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''-y'=\frac{1}{2}e^x~~~~(1)$$ Let $y'=z$, then
$$z'-z=\frac{1}{2}e^x$$ this is linear ODE where integrating factor is $e^{-x}$.
So $$z=\frac{1}{2}e^{x}\int e^{x} e^{-x} dx+Ae^{x} \implies z=\frac{1}{2}xe^x+Ae^x\implies y'=\frac{1}{2}xe^x+Ae^c$$
Integrating it we get
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^x+\frac{1}{2}xe^x+Ae^x+B$$ This may also be written as
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}xe^x+Ce^x+B,~ C=A+1/2,$$
which is the total solution of (1), where $\frac{1}{2}xe^x$ gets justified as the particular solution of (1).